# Fetching JIRA data with R

Tags: r, jira

I am able to access the data in json format from a web browser as follows

```
https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=username
```

but not able to fetch data using curl or httr libraries.

```
library(curl)
JIRAData <- curl("https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=username")

library(httr)
JIRAInfo <- GET("https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=username")
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the curl library to download the file and then parse the JSON into a dataframe after reading the file:

```
library(curl)
curl_download(url="http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data? list=englishmonarchs&format=json", destfile="mysafeinfo.json")
```

But, the jsonlite package makes this easy for you already:

```
library(jsonlite)
doc <- fromJSON(txt="http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json")
doc
                    nm            cty                        hse       yrs
1          Edmund lronside United Kingdom            House of Wessex      1016
2                     Cnut United Kingdom           House of Denmark 1016-1035
3        Harold I Harefoot United Kingdom           House of Denmark 1035-1040
4              Harthacanut United Kingdom           House of Denmark 1040-1042
5     Edward the Confessor United Kingdom            House of Wessex 1042-1066
6                Harold II United Kingdom            House of Wessex      1066
.............
```

Comment: Great answer. It works for most of the URLs.  However for fetching data from JIRA this straight forward approach is not working as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I figured out that works for me and wish to share the same:

```
library(httr)
library(tibble)     

url <- "https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=...."
res <- GET(url , authenticate(username, passcode, "basic") )
parsed_json <- enframe(unlist(content(res, "parsed"), recursive = T, use.names = T))
```